# Weirdly unable to use Mercurial/Git through proxy

Tags: git, mercurial, proxy

I can not use either Mercurial (to my BitBucket repository) or Git (to my GitHub repository) through my campus' HTTP Proxy. Last week before I left for vacation, they were working well. Now they keep giving me error 407. The weird thing is I could still browse web through my browser using the same HTTP proxy settings.

I'm not sure whether the problem is in my computer or in the campus' network. Did someone change settings on my computer or did the network admin make the HTTP proxy refuse any request from non browser application. Does anyone have any idea on how to diagnose the problem? (or any idea on what to complain and what to explain to my network administrator if the problem is in the network)

Thanks.

**update**
I mainly use HTTP Mercurial/Git access since the admins already restricted SSH access in the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 407 means "proxy authentication required" (if I recall this correct), so do you need to supply any login information to the proxy and have you configured git to do this correctly?

Comment: I have set both .hgrc http_proxy values and git http.proxy values correctly. Last week it was still working. But now it doesn't work at all, and -as I told above- I could use my browser with the same login setting as the mercurial/git. Is it possible that a proxy could distinguish mercurial/git accesses from common browser accesses and then disallow them.

Comment: That definitly is possible, the user agent string identifies what kind of program is sending the request. If this is the case (I suggest you just ask), the best thing is to determing what the user agent string of Mercurial/GIT and ask the proxy admin to accept that user agent.

Comment: If Ton is right, you could also try something like `git config --global http.useragent "Mozilla/4.0"` to make Git pretend to be a web browser.

Comment: Strange.. The mercurial/git are now working normally. It's too late to know what was the problem. I guess there were some hiccups in the network. Thank you, anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SSH or HTTP to push those changes? Your admins might have increased security so that SSH pushes don't work any more. Try to change the protocol and see if that helps. Pushing might still fail if GitHub doesn't support it but pulling should now work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I use HTTP since the admins have already restricted SSH access in the network. Last week I could still use the HTTP Mercurial/Git access normally.